# constexpr Initializer list of string views

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, constexpr, initializer-list

I'm trying to make a constexpr initializer list of some string constants. I think this should be possible in C++17, but I can't get it to compile in MSVC.

```
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

const constexpr std::initializer_list<std::string_view> some_strings{
    "asdf"sv
};
```

This gives the following error message:

```
error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
note: failure was caused by non-constant arguments or reference to a non-constant symbol
note: see usage of '$S1'
```

I can't figure out which part would be non-constexpr:

- std::string_view's operator"" is constexpr
- std::initializer_list's constructor is constexpr as well

Any ideas? Is this possibly just a bug in visual studio? What is '$S1' referenced in the error message?

EDIT: Visual Studio 15.8.9

Comment: Latest MSVC. They announced 100% conformance with the standard in 15.7, and I'm using 15.8.9.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug on older versions: https://godbolt.org/z/YICeqi

I just tried your code on v15.9.2 and it works fine.